# Zipf's Law Book Analysis using Perl

Tags: perl

Let's suppose there is a book in a text file, a public domain book so that there is no restrictions with what it is done with it, for example war of the worlds by H.G. Wells (1898):

[image]

it starts like this:

> CHAPTER ONE
>
> THE EVE OF THE WAR
>
> No one would have believed in the last years of the nineteenth century
> that this world was being watched keenly and closely by intelligences
> greater than man’s and yet as mortal as his own ...

to count the ocurrences of each word it is used the next perl script:

```
perl -0777 -lape's/\s+/\n/g' worlds.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > occurenaces.txt
```

and then is generated a text file like this:

```
   4395 the
   2317 and
   2282 of
   1524 a
   1204 I
   1155 to
    901 in
    830 was
    707 that
    557 had
    432 with
    411 my
    402 as
    ...
```

to plot it in a graph it is used:

```
gnuplot -e "set logscale y 2; set ytics 2; set grid; set title 'Occurenaces vs Word'; set xlabel 
'Word Rank'; set ylabel 'Number of Occurenaces'; set terminal png size 800,600; set output 'occurenaces.png'; plot 
'occurenaces.txt' with points pt 7 lc rgb 'red'; pause -1"
```

[image]

I have some problems, though, my script counts some words that are equal more than once, for example:

```
4395 the
340 The
```

or for example:

```
62 Martian 
12 Martian,
4 Martian’s
3 Martian.
1 Martian!’
```

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Normalizing your words by converting everything to either upper or lower case, and removing trailing punctuation characters would be a start.

Comment: As above, or using the `-i` (ingore-case) option to `sort`. Good luck.

Comment: @briandfoy Now it is just one question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a task I give in [Learning Perl](https://www.learning-perl.com) classes. In fact, I gave it to an undergraduate intern once because he had this assignment for a statistical mechanics class. Most people used some short text and manually counted. So I had him do *Moby Dick*, and then the KJV Bible. My additional instructions was to reveal the results for the Bible only after he'd blow away everyone with *Moby Dick*. Good times. Zipf takes a huge book to explain all this: *Human Behavior and the Principle of Least Effort*.

First, you probably don't want a one liner for this. There's a bit that you need to do.

- Remove all "non-text" text. There's what H.G. Wells wrote and then meta text, such as "Chapter".
- Normalize the words. "The" and "the" are the same but have different cases. "Martian" and "Martian's" is a bit different because they represent different ideas. How you judge that is up to you.
- Accumulate the counts. You don't need a pipeline here because Perl can do all of this. Using the word as a hash key already handles the uniqueness part.

```
LINE: while( <> ) {
    chomp;
    my @words = map normalize($_), split /\s+/;
    $Count{$_}++ for @words;
    }

sub normalize {
    my $s = lc shift;
    $s = s/[^a-z]//ig; # might reduce too much
    ... whatever else you need ...
    }
```

Once you have the hash, you can output it any way that you like. The keys are already unique, and you can sort them, I guess, but the plot shouldn't care.

From there you'll notice other oddities in the word list, down in the tail. You can ignore those because of their low count, but if you wanted high accuracy, you'll get into dictionaries that you maintain separately for the special cases.

Comment: well, that's a pretty nice and great answer. I have a doubt, though, if you are trying to analyze a book written in spanish, there are some words that have accent mark, for example: "aquí" perl reads it as "aquÃ". Is there a way to make perl read it as "aquí"?­

Comment: Sure. Read the input with the correct encoding. You can ask a separate question about that if you need help. :)

Comment: all right, but I am trying to find it for myself first. If I can't do it, I'll ask for help. Also, I am reading the "Llama Book" because I am completly new on Perl. I think it is a great resource, thanks a lot Brian, you are very helpful